# How to do particle binning in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, histogram, particles, binning

Currently I'm creating a particle system and I would like to transfer most of the work to the GPU using OpenGL, for gaining experience and performance reasons. At the moment, there are multiple particles scattered through the space (these are currently still created on the CPU). I would more or less like to create a histogram of them. If I understand correctly, for this I would first translate all the particles from world coordinates to screen coordinates in a vertex shader. However, now I want to do the following:

[image]

So, for each pixel a hit count of how many particles are inside. Each particle will also have several properties (e.g. a colour) and I would like to sum them for every pixel (as shown in the lower-right corner). Would this be possible using OpenGL? If so, how?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~jmesit/publications/scsc%202005.pdf) article will help you. Or [this](http://www.chrisoat.com/papers/EfficientSpatialBinning.pdf) one

Comment: [Image Load Store](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store) helpful too.

Comment: Or simply create a texture with your desired grid resolution  and increment the color for the pixel where a seed point lies in. Prior your dataset is normalized to [0, 1] coordinates of course (same as your texture size).

Comment: Thanks for the articles, they look interesting, albeit slightly overcomplicated for what I'm planning. Will have a better look at them though. 

I was hoping I could (ab)use the rasterization step between the vertex and the fragment shader, as this is basically the same operation. Would this be an option?

Comment: @meme try it out ... if it works why not :-)

Comment: Well, the point is that I don't really know how. I've worked a bit with fragment and vertex shaders, but never with the intermediate rasterization step and the documentation online is sort of sparse. For example, is there a way to obtain a list of all the points inside a fragment for the fragment shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best tool I recomend for having the whole data (if it fits on GPU memory) is the use of [SSBO](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object).

Nevertheless, you need data *after* transforming them (e.g. by a projection). Still SSBO is your best option:

In the fragment shader you read the properties of already handled particles (let's say, the rendered pixel) and write modified properties (number of particles at this pixel, color, etc) to the same index in the buffer.

Due to parallel nature of GPU, several instances coming from different particles may be doing concurrently the work for the same index. Thus you need to handle this on your own. Read [Memory model](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Memory_Model#Incoherent_memory_access) and [Atomic operations](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store#Atomic_operations)

---

Another approach, but limited, is using [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending)

The idea is that each fragment increments the actual color value of the frame buffer. This can be done using `GL_FUNC_ADD` for `glBlendEquationSeparate` and using as fragment-output-color a value of `1/255` (normalized integer) for each RGB/a component.

Limitations come from the [0-255] range: Only up to 255 particles in the same pixel, the rest amount is *clamped* to this range and so "lost".

You have four components RGBA, thus four properties can be handled. But can have several *renderbuffers* in a FBO.

You can read the FBO by `glReadPixels`. Use [glReadBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glReadBuffer) first with a `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTi` if you use a FBO instead of the default frame buffer.

Comment: The SSBO looks perfect for my use-case, but if I understand correctly it's implemented in OpenGL 4.3. I just found out MacOS apparently only supports up to 4.1 (like WTF, really Apple?!). Do you have any other suggestions?